# Native array.frombytes() (not numpy!) mysterious behavior

Tags: python, arrays, python-internals

**[I cannot use numpy so please refrain from talking about it]**

I (apparently naively) thought Python `array.frombytes()` would read from a series of bytes representing various machine format integers, depending on how you *create* the `array` object. On creation you are required to provide a letter type code telling it (or so I thought) the machine type of integer making up the byte stream.

```
import array

b = b"\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00"
a = array.array('i') #signed int (2 bytes)
a.frombytes(b)
print(a)

array('i', [131073, 262147])

and in the debugger:
array('i', [131073, 262147])
    itemsize: 4
    typecode: 'i'
```

The bytes in `b` are a series of little endian **int16s** (type code = 'i'). Despite being told this, it interpreted the bytes as 4-byte integers. This is Python 3.7.8.

I really need to convert the varying ints into an array (or list) of Python ints to deal with image data coming in byte-streams but which is actually either 16-bit or 32-bit integer, or 64 bit double floating format. What did I miss or do wrong? Or what is the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that `'i'` is the native `int` type of the underlying C compiler and is not strictly always 2 bytes.

Comment: What happened when you tried `'h'`?

Comment: @MarkRansom: No need to guess, [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) explicitly say that `'i'` corresponds to the C `signed int` type (the module documentation leads with the table giving equivalences). It gives a minimum size of two bytes, but that's to account for old/weird systems Python theoretically supports where `int` could in fact be that small; on almost every system you'll actually encounter, `int` is four bytes.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I wrote that comment before I actually looked up the documentation.  Takes a moment or two to get to the bottom of a rabbit hole.

Comment: `i` is 2 byte signed int. It still pulls 4 bytes out of the input array `b` for each step, resulting in two  32-bit ints from eight bytes, not four 16-bit ints.  Dang it.

Comment: Holy ***! 'h' does it right!@ @Kelly Bundy you got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) doesn't specify the exact size of each type, it specifies the *minimum* size.  Which means it may use a larger size if it wants, probably based on the types in the C compiler that was used to build Python.

Here are all the sizes on my system:

```
for c in 'bBuhHiIlLqQfd':
    print(c, array(c).itemsize)

b 1
B 1
u 2
h 2
H 2
i 4
I 4
l 4
L 4
q 8
Q 8
f 4
d 8
```

I would suggest using the `'h'` or `'H'` type.

Comment: If you need fixed width types, it's mildly annoying, but pretty easy, to, at global scope on import, before doing anything useful, just loop over `'hilq'`, create an `array.array` of each type, and check the typecode; first one that fits your actual data size then gets stored in a global and reused in your functions when you need to parse data. You could even create a `dict` mapping specific sizes to the corresponding codes in this pre-check, so you can handle arbitrary sizes.

Comment: @ShadowRanger usually I just use the `struct` module which is much more tightly specified.

Comment: Well, more tightly specified if you're using "standard" sizes. If you don't specify a prefix on the format string though, it's the same "corresponds to C native type" sizes, so by default, it's just as quirky.

Comment: Dang that's it!!! 'h' and 'H'. You win, thanks!!!! (Well I win too)